# List group based on Parent key value

Tags: python

Trying to build a hierarchy list by grouping based on keys - parent and account_name

```py
lst = [
    {
        "parent": "abc",
        "account_name": "abc1",
        "account_number": "119445",
    },
    {
        "parent": "abc",
        "account_name": "abc2",
        "account_number": "119446",
    },
    {
        "parent": "abc",
        "account_name": "abc2",
        "account_number": "119447",
    }
]
```

O/P desired

```py
{
    'abc': [
        {
            'abc1': ['119445'], 
            'abc2': ['119446', '119447']
        }
    ]
}
```

Tried with `setdefault`, but did not get the desired output I was looking for.

```py
parent = {}
account_name = {}
account_number = {}


for i in lst:
    j = i['account_number']
    account_name.setdefault(i['account_name'], []).append(j)
    parent.setdefault(i['parent'],[]).append(account_name)

print(parent)
```

```
{
    'abc': [
        {
            'abc1': ['119445'],
            'abc2': ['119446', '119447']
        },
        {
            'abc1': ['119445'],
            'abc2': ['119446', '119447']
        },
        {
            'abc1': ['119445'],
            'abc2': ['119446', '119447']
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a take with [`itertools.groupby`:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
parent = {}

# group by parent key
for p, data in it.groupby(lst, key=lambda d: d['parent']):

    # for each group, create a new inner dict
    inner_dict = {}

    # setdefault and append the account numbers to the list
    for d in data:
        inner_dict.setdefault(d['account_name'], []).append(d['account_number'])

    # setdefault and append the inner dict to the list
    parent.setdefault(p, []).append(inner_dict)
```

Result:

```
{
  'abc': [
    {
      'abc1': ['119445'], 
      'abc2': ['119446', '119447']
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm not too sure about the need for the inner `list` to wrap around the inner `dict`, but I trust you know better than me what you need.